# Angular 2 app With asp.net core Not working in Firefox and IE(tsconfig issue)

Tags: angular

this is a Angular 2 final version app with Visual studio 2015.
gulp is used to generate library from node modules

My app is working fine in chrome and Edge,but not working in Firefox and IE

```
   *
```

***Firefox error:***

```
    *
       Error: (SystemJS) missing = in const declaration
    @http://localhost:50135/scripts/app.module.js:13:25
    @http://localhost:50135/scripts/app.module.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:50135/scripts/app.module.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js:3:22
    @http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js:1:2
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:192:19
    Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:85:24
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:451:52
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:225:23
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:125:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:357:25
    ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:50135/libs/zone.js/dist/zone.js:297:25

    Evaluating http://localhost:[enter image description here][1]50135/scripts/app.component.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:50135/scripts/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js
    Error loading http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js
```

**this is my tsconfig**

```
    {

    "compileOnSave": true,
    "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
   "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/scripts/",
    "removeComments": false

    },
    "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "typings/index",
    "typings/index.d.ts"
    ]
    }


     **this is my package.json**

    {
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "name": "ngcorecontacts",
    "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "typings": "typings"
    },
    "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "systemjs": "0.19.38",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.23",
    "jquery": "3.1.0",

"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"

    },
    "devDependencies": {
    typescript": "^2.0.2",
    "gulp": "3.9.1",
    "path": "0.12.7",
    "gulp-clean": "0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-typescript": "^2.13.6",
    "typings": "^1.3.1",
    "gulp-tsc": "^1.2.0"
    }
    }
```

**this is my systemjs.config**

```
       System configuration for Angular 2 samples

        Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
        */
        (function (global) {
        // map tells the System loader where to look for things

        // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
        var packages = {
        app: { main: 'boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
        '@angular/core': { main: 'core.umd.min.js' },
        '@angular/common': { main: 'common.umd.min.js' },
        '@angular/compiler': { main: 'compiler.umd.min.js' },
        '@angular/platform-browser': { main: 'platform-browser.umd.min.js' },
        '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': { main: 'platform-browser-dynamic.umd.min.js' },

        };
        var map = {
        'app': 'scripts', // 'dist',
       '@angular': 'libs/@angular',
        'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'libs/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
        'rxjs': 'libs/rxjs'
        };
        var ngPackageNames = [
        'common',
        'compiler',
        'core',
        'forms',
        'http',
        'platform-browser',
        'platform-browser-dynamic',
        'router',
        'router-deprecated',
        'upgrade',
        ];
       // Individual files (~300 requests):
        function packIndex(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        }
        // Bundled (~40 requests):
        function packUmd(pkgName) {
        packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
        }
        // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
        var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
        // Add package entries for angular packages
        ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
        var config = {
        defaultJSExtensions: true,
        map: map,
        packages: packages
        };
        System.config(config);
        })(this);
```

i tried alot to solve this issue but still not working , pls guide me to solve the same.
i think its a tsconfig file issue.
this app is running fine in chrome and the same code is generate error in system.src file to load all module and bootstrap(main.ts) file

Comment: Please provide app and boot scripts

Comment: please check this link for required file...

https://github.com/nitinscorpion/Angular2/tree/master/TSscript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue appears because you've used **const** keyword in for..of loop ([here](https://github.com/nitinscorpion/Angular2/blob/master/TSscript/app.component.ts#L63)).
This is absolutely valid declaration, but it doesn't work in Edge (don't tested with Firefox). So I think, it will be better to change all occurrences to **let**

Comment: thanks  but still generating error in IE (working fine in firefox)
Error: (SystemJS) Syntax error
 SyntaxError: Syntax error
    at Anonymous function (eval code:3:1)
    at Anonymous function (eval code:1:31)
    at eval code (eval code:1:2)
 Evaluating http://localhost:50135/scripts/app.module.js
 Evaluating http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js
 Error loading http://localhost:50135/scripts/boot.js 
   {
      [functions]: ,
      __proto__: { },
      description: "(SystemJS) Syntax error
 SyntaxError: Syntax error
    at Anonymous function (eval code:3:1)

Answer (score 1):

Your target is "target": "es6".

Firefox does not support fully ES6 yet, you can see here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/ECMAScript_6_support_in_Mozilla

### Features not compliant with the ES6 specification (Last updated Sep 19, 2016, 4:34:50 PM)

The following features are (partially) implemented in Firefox, but are not compliant with the specification. There are a couple of possible reasons for this: Firefox's implementation is based on an older draft of the ES6 specification, or Firefox's current implementation is an experimental design added before a similar feature was added to the ES6 specification.

- Legacy iterators and generators (JS 1.7, Firefox 2)
- Destructuring assignment (JS 1.7, Firefox 2) (ES6 compliance bug 1055984)
- const (JS 1.5, Firefox 1.0) (ES6 compliance bug 950547 implemented in Firefox 51)
- let (JS 1.7, Firefox 2) (ES6 compliance bug 950547 implemented in Firefox 51)

You can change your target to ES5 to ensure compatibility.

Hope this helps

Comment: this link is not helpful for me , i am already tried es5 , but my code get some error ..pls suggest me any other idea to solve this problem..